# I want to copy my present working directory location into abc.text file by replacing some sentence

Tags: command-line, scripts, c

I want to copy my present working directory location into abc.text file by replacing some sentence.

For example, 4th line of abc.text is "my name is narender" and i want replace pwd path instead of "my name is narender". please help

Comment: It is not clear how one can copy a directory to a file.

Comment: @Pilot6 OP says "I want to copy my present working directory location into abc.text" and also "pwd path". Not the directory itself.

Answer (score 4):

Using sed for in-place replacement.

```bsh
$ sed -i "s|replace me|$PWD|g" text.txt
```

<sup>(remember that characters in the $variable will interfere with the sed expression).</sup>

sed option:

- `-i[suffix]`
  Edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied).

bash variables:

- `$PWD`
  The current working directory as set by the cd command.

Further reading:

[Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/12007102)

Comment: Nice how you made the OP's homework. In order not to rely on environment variables, you could replace $PWD by $(pwd). Sure it will work all right like this with the spaces in "replace me" or potentially in $PWD?

Comment: @bac0n Without specifying the beginning `^` and the end `$` of the string, this could give undesired results. Kindly look into this `pwd | xargs --replace=PWD sed -i 's|^my name is narender$|PWD|' abc.text`. Thank you +1

Comment: @Raffa just at first glance, "--replace" is deprecated, xargs will not protect its own args from "too long arguments". I think OP just  want to replace text like %cookie%.

Comment: more worried about $PWD breaking sed expression.